# How do you remove a dummy knob with a screw that seems to spin and spin?

Tags: doors, hardware, knobs

I recently purchased my first home and wanted to replace all of the door knobs to make it feel more like **my** place, rather than just some place I was renting again.  Anyway, all of the privacy locking knobs, closet knobs, and even the deadbolts on exterior doors were pretty easy for a novice like me to remove and replace.

Unfortunately, there are a lot of closets in this condo and therefore there are a lot of dummy knobs that need replacing.  I thought these would be the easiest to do, but I was hit by a curve ball:

The dummy knobs that came with the condo seem to have an extra screw - beyond the two that you can unscrew from the front.  This third one goes from the back of the door, through a washer, then through a hole in the door and into the knob.   I tried to unscrew it, but can't seem to get anywhere. It just sits and spins.  This leads me to believe there is some kind of nut on the inside of the handle, but I have no idea how to access this nut (or really, if I'm even on the right track).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After removing the two screws on the handle, you may need to pull on the handle (away from the 3rd screw) to provide some resistance so the screw can begin unthreading.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a screw head on the inside of the door at the same position as the knob on the outside.

Hold that still with a screwdriver while you unscrew the knob from the front.

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't seem to do anything... I'll try again when I get home, though.

Comment: @Jason - if it still doesn't work (see also @mohlsen's answer) post small photos of both sides of the door.